# .Net Framework issue with RTZ2 time zone

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, .net-4.5

It seems we have found an issue with RTZ2 timezone (Russian Standard Time) in .Net Framework 4.5.

If you try to convert time between 2014-01-01 00:00:00 and 2014-01-01 00:59:59 (in RTZ2 timezone) to UTC, you get an error: `The supplied DateTime represents an invalid time.  For example, when the clock is adjusted forward, any time in the period that is skipped is invalid.`

Example (https://dotnetfiddle.net/rNbp8F):

```
var rtz2 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Russian Standard Time");
var moment = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
var utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(moment, rtz2); // throws an exception
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Works fine, you must document your local timezone.  Also rather unlikely you actually have 4.5

Comment: @HansPassant - local time zone doesn't come into play with the provided code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to [KB3012229](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3012229), which was fixed with .NET 4.6.

If you have .NET 4.6 installed, the exception will not be thrown - even if you are targeting .NET 4.0 through 4.5.2 - because they are all in-place upgrades.

The exception *does* reproduce on .NET 3.5, or on .NET 4.0 through .NET 4.5.2 if you do not have .NET 4.6 installed.

There are a few things you can do here:

- **Option 1:**  Leave your code as-is, and update to the latest .NET 4.6 (or install one of the hotfixes now available in the KB article)
- **Option 2:** Change your code to use a function such as this:

  ```
  private DateTime Rtz2ToUtc(DateTime dt)
  {
      if (dt.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc)
          return dt;

      if (dt.Year < 2011)
      {
          var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Russian Standard Time");
          return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, tz);
      }

      var transition = new DateTime(2014, 10, 26, 2, 0, 0);
      var offset = TimeSpan.FromHours(dt < transition ? 4 : 3);
      return new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset).UtcDateTime;
  }
  ```
- **Option 3:** Change your code to use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) and [TZDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) time zones:

  ```
  private DateTime Rtz2ToUtc(DateTime dt)
  {
      if (dt.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc)
          return dt;

      DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Moscow"];
      LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dt);
      return ldt.InZoneLeniently(tz).ToDateTimeUtc();
  }
  ```

Personally, I prefer Option 3, as TZDB time zones are much more accurate than Windows time zones.  You can read more in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score -1):

Try this out :

```
var rtz2 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Russian Standard Time");
var offset = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1));
var timeSpan = rtz2.GetUtcOffset(offset);
```

You can now create the UTC DateTime by using timeSpan :

```
var utc = offset.Add(timeSpan);
// 1/1/2014 4:00:00 AM -06:00
```

Comment: Constructing a `DateTimeOffset` from a `DateTime` that has `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` assumes the computer's *local* time zone.