# Global issues about C# DateTime/TimeZone UTC time calculation

Tags: c#, json, datetime, timezone, utc

I'm from Turkey and our government decided not to change Daylight Saving Time Settings anymore, starting this year *(October 2016)*. So, there already have been some published updates on Windows, related with this subject. But we are still having problems on some of our Windows 2012 R2 servers when we try to get a UTC time from old date values on C# side.

Here is an example logging from my local PC and from a server:

```
var createdOn = new DateTime(2009, 8, 20, 0, 0, 0);
_logger.Debug(string.Format("Field CREATED_ON: {0}, WITH-TIMEZONE-FORMAT: {1}",  createdOn, createdOn.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss tt \"GMT\"zzz")));
_logger.Debug(string.Format("UTC-DATETIME: {0}, UTC-TZ:{1}", createdOn.ToUniversalTime(), createdOn.ToUniversalTime().ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss tt \"GMT\"zzz")));
```

**On my Local PC :**

```
Field CREATED_ON: 20.08.2009 00:00:00, WITH-TIMEZONE-FORMAT: 20.08.2009 00:00:00 ÖÖ GMT+03:00
UTC-DATETIME: 19.08.2009 21:00:00, UTC-TZ:19.08.2009 21:00:00 ÖS GMT+03:00
```

**On Server :**

```
Field CREATED_ON: 20.8.2009 00:00:00, WITH-TIMEZONE-FORMAT: 20.08.2009 00:00:00  GMT+04:00    
UTC-DATETIME: 19.8.2009 20:00:00, UTC-TZ:19.08.2009 20:00:00  GMT+04:00
```

As you can see, on the server, I get the UTC time 1 hour before than it should be and it thinks the time zone should be +4 for that day, which is wrong. And this issue eventually causes big problems, such as getting a wrong date value for JSON serialization, since Microsoft converts dates to long numbers based on their UTC time equivalent..

My question here, what is the possible thing we're missing. We do not update our servers regularly, but we have installed the update packages related with this time zone updates. And it worked on some servers, but not on some others. We're trying to find out any articles or update documents to channel us to right direction, but so far we got nothing.

--

Comment: We can't really tell what's producing that output as you haven't provided any code at all. I'm sure if you provide the code, it will be easier to help you. You should also compare the servers that work with the ones that don't *really carefully* - it sounds to me like you may have missed some relevant updates.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, since i was only logging the DateTime value and its UTC value, i didn't think a code block was necessary. But i added the logging code sample too. And also, we made the same changes on both Windows servers which gives us the different results.. I'm only suspected if it is related with previous updates too also, but i'm seeking for a confirmation for it before we try installing all past updates.

Comment: Are you certain both machines have the *exact* same time zone settings? If you could change your sample to explicitly use a specific `TimeZoneInfo` for example, that would make it easier to reproduce. (I don't think there's much benefit in logging it just as a `DateTime` and then as a `DateTime` in a specific format, btw.)

Comment: Are you sure that these are Windows Server 2012R2 machines?  If they were Windows Server 2003, machines the warning in the box titled "Important" [in these MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx) would explain this behavior.

Comment: Also, you can check the `TzVersion` number under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones` to see if the machine has been updated or not.

Comment: @JonSkeet  We installed all Windows Updates on the troubled server, but the problem is still in the same state.. Windows time zone settings are just the same on servers with "Istanbul +3 - Turkey Standart Time". We logged and compared many thing from `TimeZoneInfo` class and `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone`, such as `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges()` `timeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules()` .. We compared registry records  too.. Nothing seems to be different and we are more lost more we try.. @peter-smith

Comment: @JonSkeet @MattJohnson We are also sure that the server is 2012 R2 definitely.. I checked the warning on the MSDN document that Matt has linked before, it says that for XP based systems. Our OS version is `Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0` and running Framework version is `4.0.30319.34209`

Comment: Okay, so if you've logged things with `TimeZoneInfo`, do you mean you get all the same results there? Again, it would be really useful to see a [mcve] which demonstrates this. One thing to check: in the date/time zone settings, there's a check box for "observe daylight saving time". Is that the same on all your servers?

Comment: This may be related to [KB3012229](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3012229).  Your .net version (4.0.30319.34209) is associated with .NET Framework 4.5.2, and that bug was fixed with 4.6 and later.  You could try updating to the latest .NET Framework, or if you must stay on 4.5.2 you can install the first hotfix in the list in the KB article.  Note the KB talks about Russian time zones, but the same scenario would reflect in the latest Turkish time zone data.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/32316380/634824